# C99 How to get a warning when assigning a non-void pointer to void?

Tags: c, pointers, warnings, assign

Is there an option in the major compilers (specifically GCC or Clang) to show a warning when doing this:

```
int x;
float *y = &x; // incompatible pointer type warning
void *p = &x; // the compiler doesn't complain, I want a warning there too
```

I want it for safety, and I'd silent it with an explicit cast if needed.

Comment: That's the point of the `void*` - you can't do anything *else* with it.

Comment: The standard explicitly allows the conversion from or to `void*`. However, read the standard for caveats.

Comment: You'll get a warning if you compile using C++, but the C standard uses `void` pointers specifically to allow for these conversions (i.e., from the pointer returned by `malloc` to a the pointer type of your choice).

Comment: C is not strictly typed. Unless you use static code analysers, you have to live with that. If you want a warning about invalid pointer types, just don't use `void *`. I mean, how would the compiler know when to warn and when not? ´void *` is exactly there for this reason in C. And regarding "silence with a cast when needed": that could be fatal, unless you really understand **all** implications.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed for Needing Details/Clarity. It seems perfectly clear what the OP wants, and the answer may simply be that it's not possible to do this. I'm voting to reopen.